# What is a Stereo Type

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I've searched through the Orchard documentation (along with some google-fu) and couldn't find anything that explains what a StereoType is and when (if possible) is it appropriate to create or extend one.

Can someone please explain what they are?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Think of it as a content type category. Examples are widgets, menu items. You can absolutely come up with your own, if you are building a feature that needs to work on more than one content type that have something essential in common.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense... Perhaps a note about stereotypes could be added to the docs somewhere?? :P

Comment: I have read that stereotypes can also alter the rendering. I have tried to find a list of stereotypes for orchard. I think this needs to be better documented too.